# WPF .NET 5 (XAML) Add some labels when i press button

Tags: c#, xaml, button, label

I'm new. I'm learning C# .NET 5. I want to create in XAML dynamic Labels when i press add_button the labels appears in the new line under. I'm using Visual Studio 2022. I dont know what to write in MainWindow.xaml.cs.

Thanks for some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Button click event. In the event you can add some labels on a [StackPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/stackpanel?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). StackPanel will help when you add something new it will be under the last one.

In XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DemoTryThings.MainWindow"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DemoTryThings"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<!--Main Grid!-->
<Grid Margin="10">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                x:Name="LabelStackPanel"/>

    <Button Grid.Row="1"
            Height="30"
            Content="Add Label"
            Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>

</Grid>
```

In cs file:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LabelStackPanel.Children.Add(new Label { Content = "Hi this add with button click!" });
    }
}
```

And result: [image]

Comment: Thank You. And i have another question about LabelStackPanel.Children.Add. Can i add TextBlock or TextBlock in the same way as Label but without StackPanel? I trying this :        
            TextBlock textBox1 = new TextBlock();
            textBox1.Text = "Text Box content";
            textBoxDodawany.Children.Add(textBox1);

Comment: I don’t think so you can add a control inside textblock. But you can use something like that, you can use one text block and you can say textblock.text += “your text\n” it will still look like with new line.